# Python MQTT publisher doesn't publish

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

Trying to publish some data from a raspberry pi, but nothing gets through. However, publishing via MQTT.fx works fine. This is my python script:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

publish.single("example_topic", payload="example message", qos=0, retain=False,\
         hostname="example.com",port=8883, client_id="random_number", \
        keepalive=60, will=None,auth = {'username':"example_username",\
         'password':"example_password"}, tls=None, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311, transport="tcp")
```

This might be important to know: In MQTT.fx I wasn't able to connect without navigating to "SSL/TLS", making a cross next to "Enable SSL/TLS" and then making a cross next to "CA signed server certificate".

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing different things up here. The `publish.single` doesn't need any of the `mqtt.Client()` stuff. It is designed to to EVERYTHING in a single function call.

`publish.single()` takes options for everything. The docs are [here](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#single)

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

publish.single(topic, payload=None, qos=0, retain=False, hostname="localhost",
        port=1883, client_id="", keepalive=60, will=None, 
        auth={username:"user", password:"pass"}, tls=None,
        protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311, transport="tcp")
```

Comment: thanks! however, since there is still no response, I've edited the post to mirror the new approach.  In the documentation you provided it states:

"tls - 
a dict containing TLS configuration parameters for the client:

dict = {‘ca_certs’:”<ca_certs>”, ‘certfile’:”<certfile>”, ‘keyfile’:”<keyfile>”, ‘tls_version’:”<tls_version>”, ‘ciphers’:”<ciphers”>}"

This, to me, is not very helpful. How can I specify the "CA signed server certificate" thing?

Comment: The same way the `auth` options are passed in the example.

Comment: I changed tsl=None to tls={'ca_certs':"CA signed server certificate"} and I get the following error:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 772, in tls_set
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: You need to pass the file name of the file that holds the CA chan that signed the certificate from the broker. The doc does say this: https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#tls-set

Comment: it works. it was done with the "certifi" package. i.e. tls= {'ca_certs':certifi.where(), 'tls_version':ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2}